# What would be the return type of this method in groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a method such as this:

```
def getInformation ()  {

  return [true, "reason why"]
}
```

which I'm using like this

```
def (isClear, reason) = getInformation()
```

Is there way to define a return type for this method so its better to read when someone is going through the method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The real return type of this method is Object, since you declared it using 'def'. This means it can return anything, regardless of the object you're actually returning.

The following code would be just as valid:

```
def getInformation ()  {    
  return "this is some information"
}
```

or

```
def getInformation ()  {    
  return 42
}
```

But the returntype of the method hasn't changed.

The real question here is: why would you choose such an approach? In my opinion, the following would make things so much more clear:

```
Result getInformation() {
     return new Result(success: true, reason: "why")
}
```

This would make it much more clear to the caller, and the only thing you'd need to create is a trivial class:

```
class Result {
     boolean success
     String reason
}
```

Now you've got a clearly defined API. I would never use def in a method signature, because of the problem you're facing here.

Comment: i like that approach. however this will be the only instance where I'll require this class. making a new class just for that purpose seems bit much...

Comment: If i make this class. Where would be the best place to put it? The function in question is in my service class. Should I put the `Result` class in `src/groovy`?

Comment: +1, also you can still keep the same multiple assignment syntax by implementing `getAt(Integer)` in your Result class: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/groovy-goodness-multiple-assignments.html

Comment: Also, that conceptually looks more like a Tuple: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Why-has-groovy-no-built-in-tuple-support-like-map-and-lists-td360532.html

Comment: Hi Anthony, I'm not sure why creating a new class would be to much. Like I said, it makes it much clearer to the caller. Also, the question you accepted as the right answer is not right. You asked for the return type of the method, and it's Object, not List. I'm not saying this is the best answer there is, but at least it's more right :)

Comment: You are wrong. The actual type here is List. def just mean that the type will be resolved dynamicly in runtime.

Comment: Mr Cat, sorry, you are wrong. The question here is what is the return type of the method, not the type of object returned by the method, which is clearly a list. Check the following example, which might clear things up?

class Y {
    def x() { 
        [] 
    }
}

assert Object == Y.class.methods.find {it.name == "x" }.returnType

Answer (score 11):

Anthony, better in your case to return a map `[isClear:true, reason:"reason why"]`. Then in your code get values:

```
Map getInformation ()  {
  return [isClear:true, reason:"reason why"]
}
...
def result =  getInformation ()
if(result.isClear){
   ...
   result.reason
   ...
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong; it doesn't run. You are specifying to return a Map, while in reality you are returning a List. I changed the example for you.

Answer (score 8):

The return type will be List, more exactly ArrayList with two elements of type Boolean, String

And as a generic List can only be of a single type (in this case Object), there is no way you can define several return types.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there way to define a return type for this method so its better to read when someone is going through the method?

Not really, you could change it to this, but it's not much better:

```
List getInformation ()  {
  return [true, "reason why"]
}
```

However, you can define the types of the variables that are assigned the return values, which makes that part of the code more readable.

```
def getInformation ()  {    
  return [true, "reason why"]
}

def (boolean isClear, String reason) = getInformation()
```